# How to mount squashfs (embedded-linux) on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, squashfs

I have tried to mount a filesystem from a firmware (embedded-linux) but it failed on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Could you tell me how to mount that file system? (or possible reasons of the failure). Details are as follows.

### Details

Step1)
Analyzing the firmware using binwalk shows starting address of squashfs filesystem. Thus I generated squashfs filesystem using "dd" linux utility.

Step2)
The analysis of generated filesystem using "binwalk ./fs.img" command shows:

```
Squashfs filesystem, big endian, lzma signatrue, version 3.0, size: XXXXXXX bytes, XXX inodes, blocksize: XXXXX bytes, created: xxxx
```

Step3) "mount -o loop ./fs.img ./fs" failed. "dmesg | tail" shows:

```
SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on loop1
```

How can I mount that file system? FYI,
I installed latest squashfs-tools with lzma support from "sourceforge.net/procjects/squashfs".

Comment: IIRC you may omit the -o loop on FSimages, but anyway: Does it work if you mount it read-only? You could also try to use 'unsquashfs'...

Comment: It does not work even if I omiited "-o loop" option (also read-only mount). Also I tried unsquashfs, but I got the same error message in Step3.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. Since my configuration did not support `zlib`, I used `xz` compression instead as it was supported in my configuration. The following worked:

```
mksquashfs source source.sqfs -comp xz
mount source.sqfs destination
```